# Python (2.7): are functions computationally expensive

Tags: python, function, python-2.7, performance

Are functions computationally expensive in python? For instance, if I have numerous loops and I call functions that i have defined, is that much more expensive that writing the material of the function in the main code?

What should a good programmer try to do to make his code as efficient as possible?

Comment: theyre more expensive than no function .... but not very expensive (and certainly not expensive enough to worry about...) if you are that concerned with performance python likely is not the right language for the problem you are working on...

Comment: The [```timeit``` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html) answers your second question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The overhead a the function call is relatively insignificant compared to what you're doing inside it... It's better to have a clean code with several functions which realize one job instead of a spaghetti code of 1000 lines unreadable. In Python (and it should be the case in every language), [*Readability counts*](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/).

However, the overhead **can be significant** (create the stack, return the value, jump to code address, etc.) if you're calling the function *a lot*. Instead of manipulate a single data for example, a function may works with iterator and returns the result applied on the iterator:

```
res = []
for x in elems:
     res.append(my_function(x))


res = my_function(x)  # this solution is way better for performance
```

If you want to estimate the cost of a function call, you can time it with... the [`timeit` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html) :)

Answer (score 2):

Python calls have a small overhead, in that the current frame is pushed on the stack and a new frame needs to be created for the code object that is being called.

But this overhead is relatively small, and unless you call a small function continuously in a loop, you won't notice this fixed cost.

You should always analyze your actual algorithm for its computational complexity and try to minimize that first. Only *then* should you look at inlining functions. Use the [`timeit` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html) to measure timing differences between your options.

But also remember the [Zen of Python](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/):

> - Readability counts.

Functions, when used right, increase the readability of your code. Don't go overboard trying to throw them out at the gain of minute performance improvements.